# Flutter StreamBuilder using AWS AppSync Or DataStore

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, graphql, aws-amplify

I am building an application using AWS AppSync which fetches the Posts from the AWS Appsync and is rendered via the FutureBuilder Widget > ListView.Builder
Is there a way I can grab it as a stream and use a stream view builder to render the same as there is no official documentation provided by AWS Amplify regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, it is possible to have a SusbcriptionEvent of the object and then listen to the stream.

```
Stream<SubscriptionEvent<Post>> stream =
Amplify.DataStore.observe(Post.classType);
stream.listen((event) {
print('Received event of type ' + event.eventType.toString());
print('Received post ' + event.item.toString());
});
```

An alternative is using a StreamBuilder, you could create a function that returns the stream

```
Stream postStream() {
  Stream<SubscriptionEvent<Post>> stream =
    Amplify.DataStore.observe(Post.classType);

  return stream;
}
```

And then use a StreamBuilders to listen to the stream being returned by the function.

```
StreamBuilder<SubscriptionEvent<Post>>(
                stream: postStream(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Text('No data');
                  }
                  if (snapshot.hasError ||
                      snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return Text('Loading...');
                  }

                  print("snapshot ${snapshot.data.item.title}");
                  print("snapshot ${snapshot.data.item.rating.toString()}");

                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(snapshot.data.item.title),
                      Text(snapshot.data.item.rating.toString()),
                    ],
                  );
                }),
```